# Running Python scripts(modules) under Windows XP

Tags: python, configuration, installation, windows-xp

Problem is with running Python scripts(modules) under Windows XP.

Yesterday I installed Python 3.3.0 version for Windows. The problem **is that I CAN use** command line and IDLE to calculate (it works without errors in output), but if I try simple ***print "Hello."*** , output in command prompt, and in GUI IDLE shows me:

```
Syntax error: invalid syntax
```

Path variable is set to default directory "C:\Python33\", and again I can use it for calculation, but running examples from online resources or that simple stuff is currently for me impossible.

Comment: Python 3 has many changes from Python 2. See http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html for an overview.

Comment: So basicly most examples from 2.x version doesn't work in 3.x version.

Comment: Many examples *do* run, most others are easily translated. But it's easier for you, as a python beginner, to stick with Python 2 if your tutorials assume Python 2.

Comment: Ok Martijn, I wll probably do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use something like `print("hello")` in python 3.x

`print` has been converted to a function in python 3.x.

read this :`[Print is a function](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function)

```
Python 3.1.2 (release31-maint, Dec  9 2011, 20:50:50) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print 3
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print 3
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> print(3)                  # works fine
3
```